# Meaning of support vectors in support vector regression

Tags: regression, machine-learning, svm, kernel-trick

I know that the support vectors in a soft margin SVM classifier model essentially means the vectors on the margin or less than the margin(the ones within the tube containing the decision boundary), and that they have their Lagrange multipliers $\alpha_i$ as non-zero, and specifically $0 <\alpha_i<C$, thus contributing to the weights.

Now, in a support vector regression model, as some of the lectures said, **the ones within the tube**(the one containing the fitted-curve and of width $2\epsilon$) have their $\xi_i$ as zero, as their error falls within the required value, and thus **have their** **$\alpha_i$ as zero**.
And that **the ones outside the tube have their $\xi_i$ as positive and thus their $\alpha_i$ as positive**. Does this mean that support vectors in an SVR model are the ones outside the tube, as opposed to the classic SVM model? **What are the support vectors in the SVR model?**